# Android TextView align text vertically within the bounding box

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-xml

> **Note:** I am troubling aligning text within the bounding box not within the parent view.

This happens when I apply `background color` to the `TextView` so I can reduce one parent layout just to add background color

[image]

#### XML File

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/item_card"
    style="@style/CardViewTheme"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_item_icon"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/item_name"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_name"
            style="@style/BodyMenuText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Flat Tire"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/item_price"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_icon" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorDarkestGray"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="USD 40"
            android:textSize="@dimen/app_caption_text"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/item_name" />

    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Use android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" if your goal is to make text center of parent layout.

Comment: @HariRam Did you ready my `Note` in quote? If not please read it.

Comment: We need the entire XML document.

Comment: @CodeLover Box just is background color? or you have some other view for that?

Comment: @GavinWright I have updated question with full XML code..

@HariRam Yes I have applied background color to the `TextView` itself so I do not have to add one parent layout just to set the background color.

Comment: @GavinWright `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` is the issue here, if you can give a fixed height to the text view, your issue should be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your solution:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/item_card"
      android:layout_width="96dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
      app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
```

The layout_height of your `CardView` wasn't high enough and the bottom of the `TextView` was getting cut off. Setting it to `wrap_content` does the trick.

Comment: Sorry i didn't know that your updating your answer,

Comment: +1 - Just one question.. why the fixed size affect the 'TextView'? and what I I have to set the fixed size here?

Comment: You could just increase the fixed size, say from 96dp to 110dp. But wrap_content seems like the better solution.

Comment: Ah! so stupid I am :P. I see what you mean.. it is cropping the bottom part when height is fixed.. Got it.. Thanks a lot..